# Process querystring or similar using wp-ajax.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying in Wordpress using the ajax-php to call a function only if a query string or similar has a value of 1. In the admin area, I have created a new page using `add_submenu_page()` containing only a button for now. When clicking that button I want to do something like:

1. set a variable or a query string to 1. (like www.myurl.com/?mystring=1)
2. check whether its set to 1 or not.
3. if set to 1, call a function.

How would I do this? Thanks for all help!

Currently, my code is looking like this:

functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_custom_action', array($this, 'mediabank_admin_import_posts'));
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_action', array($this, 'mediabank_admin_import_posts'));

function mediabank_admin_import_posts() {
  if(!isset($_POST['import_posts_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['import_posts_nonce'], 'mediabank_admin_import_posts_nonce')) {
    exit('Not valid form');
  }

  //process/call function
}
```

html (present on a page in wp-admin)

```
<div class="wrap">
  <form id="import-posts" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="mediabank_admin_import_posts">    
  <?php wp_nonce_field('mediabank_admin_import_posts_nonce', 'import_posts_nonce'); ?>
  <button id="import_posts" class="button button-primary button-large">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Js

```
$(function() {
  $('#import_posts').on('submit', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   var form = $(this);

   $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(data) {
     alert('data ' + data);
   }, 'json');
 })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your JS you can get the form data like so:

Js:

```
$('#import-posts').on("change", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = $('.filters-form').serialize();
  aJaxFilter(formData);
});

function aJaxFilter(formData) {
  $.ajax({
    url: js_variables.ajaxURL,
    type:'GET',
    data: {
      'formData' : formData,
      'action' : 'yourFunctionName'
    },
    success:function(data){
      $('.YourContainer').html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

In your functions.php you need to enqueue the JS variable, like so:

functions.php:

```
function scripts() {
  wp_localize_script ('scripts', 'js_variables', array ('js_home_url' => 
  home_url(), 'ajaxURL' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), ''));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts' );
```

Create a new called something like ajax-function.php. In that, put the following:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_yourFunctionName', 'yourFunctionName');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_yourFunctionName', 'yourFunctionName');

function yourFunctionName() {
  // your code in here
}
```

This should work to be able to submit your form. On submit, it should make an AJAX request with the form data. What you want from the callback function, you need to put inside yourFunctionName(). You then need to make sure that in AjaxFilter, you state where you want the data to be placed.

Might not have completely hit the mark yet, so give it a try and let me know what else needs to be implemented.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for posting. Basically what i want to do is when i click the submit button call a function in php. I dont want the page to refresh, hence i want to do it with ajax. I suppose that i need to use a query string for that? In order to do error handling?

Comment: Okay, so you want to pass the form data to an AJAX function on submit?

Comment: Hey! Does the same code you provided also apply if I'm developing a custom plugin? Can I use it in my plugin file rather than functions.php?

Comment: This has a really useful video on the topic: https://www.creare.co.uk/blog/wp/how-to-enqueue-scripts-stylesheets-to-wordpress-via-a-plugin

Comment: Yes, I have experience in plugin development. I was just of the impression that it has to be done in the theme itself.

Comment: Ahhh, well you can make a folder in the plugins file called, for instance, myScripts. in there you can make myScripts.php. In that file, add the relevant plugin comments at the top, and then you can just add the enqueue scripts in there

Comment: Could you please provide an example?